# Thread query SDL_Net

Tags: c++, networking, sdl, sdl-net

Running my listen function in a seperate thread seems to use up a lot of CPU
Is it considered ok to use Delays to reduce cpu usage or am I using threads all wrong ?

```
// Running in a seperate Thread
void Server::listen()
{ 
    while (m_running)
    {
        if (SDLNet_UDP_Recv(m_socket, m_packet) > 0)
        {
              //Handle Packet Function
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the socket a non-blocking socket?

Comment: Also, remember that [`SDLNet_UDP_Recv`](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDLNet_UDP_Recv) returns `-1` *on error*, which is non-zero and therefore true. You need to do e.g. `if (SDLNet_UDP_Recv(...) > 0)`

Comment: I am 99% sure they are blocking. Also I do have > 0, I just quickly type out a minimal example. Apologies for the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the `SDLNet_UDP_Recv` reference](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDLNet_UDP_Recv)

> This is a non-blocking call, meaning if there's no data ready to be received the function will return.

That means if there's nothing to receive then `SDLNet_UDP_Recv` will return immediately with `0` and your loop will iterate and call `SDLNet_UDP_Recv` again which returns `0` and so on. This loop will never sleep of pause, so of course it will use as much CPU as it can.

A possible solution is indeed to add some kind of delay or sleep in the loop.

I would suggest something like

```
while (m_running)
{
    int res;
    while (m_running && (res = SDLNet_UDP_Recv(...)) > 0)
    {
        // Handle message
    }

    if (res < 0)
    {
        // Handle error
    }
    else if (m_running /* && res == 0 */)
    {
        // Small delay or sleep
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my main issue was if using a SDL_Delay was a valid solution. Sorry yes, non blocking also. Not with it today.